# Parameter ESTimation (PEST) algorithm? Steps and purposes?

Tags: algorithms

I'm reading up on the Parameter ESTimation algorithm, (Link to PEST homepage [1](http://www.pesthomepage.org/)), and having trouble understanding the broad strokes, as I keep getting lost in null spaces, different regularized ion techniques, etc.

Can someone who is familiar with this algorithm, often used in the calibration of environment models, provide a broad outline of its steps and the purpose of each step?

It is based on the Gauss-Marquadt-Levenberg algorithm and uses many different types of "regularization".

Edit: I understand the part of the algorithm relate to the method of Steepest Descent, but not the Gauss-Newton algorithm part or how it combines these two methods into one.

Much thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! Are you interested in a specific parameter estimation algorithm? If so, could you please provide a reference? (There are many such algorithms.) As currently posed, your question is very broad, and narrowing the focus would make it both more useful and easier to answer.

Comment: What aspects of the Gauss-Marquadt-Levenberg algorithm do you understand?

Comment: @Paul, I edited the question to provide a little info on what I understand.

Comment: Even with the edits, this question is still very broad.  Can you state a question about a particular section of the PEST documentation?  Are you simply looking for general references on methods for nonlinear least squares problems (Gauss-Newton, Levenberg-Marquardt, etc.)?